# GWT remote logging going to System.out instead of log file

Tags: gwt

I have setup gwt remote logging based on the gwt documentation, however my logs are going to System.out instead of being written to a log file.

My gwt module looks like:

```
<module rename-to='ezdappserver'>

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINEST"/>
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
</module>
```

My servlet definition is setup like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ezdappserver/remote_logging</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When an error is logged I see output in my console like so:

```
Mar 26, 2014 2:10:36 PM com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceUtil logOnServer
SEVERE: Exception caught: (NotFoundError) 
....Rest of error....
```

I was expecting this output to be written to a log file somewhere in my war. Also, I would really like to be able to specify where this file is located, however I haven't been able to find any documentation on that either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE: I am not running this through dev mode, this is with compiled code.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `log4j.xml` in your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below options also in `gwt.xml` based on your requirement:

```
<!-- This handler sends log messages to the server, where they will be logged using the server side logging mechanism. -->     
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />  
<!-- Logs by calling method GWT.log. These messages can only be seen in Development Mode in the DevMode window. -->
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />  
<!-- These messages can only be seen in Development Mode in the DevMode window. -->
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<!-- Logs to the popup which resides in the upper left hand corner of application when this handler is enabled. -->
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<!-- Logs to the javascript console, which is used by Firebug Lite (for IE), Safari and Chrome. -->
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="DISABLED"/> 
<!-- Logs to the firebug console. -->
<set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="DISABLED" />
```

---

If above configuration are still not working for you then try below code along with above configuration.

Add `log4j.xml` file to define the log file location with log level

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="DT=> %d [%.4t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SERVER_FILE_LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/logs/DataTools_Server.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%.4t] %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CLIENT_FILE_LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/logs/DataTools_Client.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%.4t] %-5p %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="com.x.y.server">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="SERVER_FILE_LOG" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </category>

    <category name="gwtRemoteLogging">
        <priority value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="CLIENT_FILE_LOG" />
    </category>

    <root> 
        <priority value ="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="SERVER_FILE_LOG" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Define you own logging servlet by implementing `RemoteLoggingService`

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import com.google.gwt.logging.server.StackTraceDeobfuscator;
import com.google.gwt.logging.shared.RemoteLoggingService;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * The Class GwtRemoteLogging.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GwtRemoteLogging extends RemoteServiceServlet implements RemoteLoggingService {

    /** The Constant logger. */
    private StackTraceDeobfuscator deobfuscator = null;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("gwtRemoteLogging");

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }

    /**
     * Logs a Log Record which has been serialized using GWT RPC on the server.
     * 
     * @return either an error message, or null if logging is successful.
     */
    public final String logOnServer(LogRecord lr) {
        try {
            if (lr.getLevel().equals(Level.SEVERE)) {
                logger.error(lr.getMessage(),lr.getThrown());
            } else if (lr.getLevel().equals(Level.INFO)) {
                logger.info(lr.getMessage(),lr.getThrown());
            } else if (lr.getLevel().equals(Level.WARNING)) {
                logger.warn(lr.getMessage(),lr.getThrown());
            } else if (lr.getLevel().equals(Level.FINE)) {
                logger.debug(lr.getMessage(),lr.getThrown());
            } else {
                logger.trace(lr.getMessage(),lr.getThrown());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Remote logging failed", e);
            return "Remote logging failed, check stack trace for details.";
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * By default, this service does not do any deobfuscation. In order to do server side
     * deobfuscation, you must copy the symbolMaps files to a directory visible to the server and
     * set the directory using this method.
     * 
     * @param symbolMapsDir
     */
    public void setSymbolMapsDirectory(String symbolMapsDir) {
        if (deobfuscator == null) {
            deobfuscator = new StackTraceDeobfuscator(symbolMapsDir);
        } else {
            deobfuscator.setSymbolMapsDirectory(symbolMapsDir);
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.x.y.server.servlet.GwtRemoteLogging</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ezdappserver/remote_logging</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up implementing my own remote logging class like you suggested and it works great!

Answer (score 2):

The `RemoteServiceServlet` uses `java.util.logging` to log, and [by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a1.9) it logs to the console (`System.err`, not `System.out` BTW).

If you want to log to a file, then you have to configure `java.util.logging`; either editing your global `lib/logging.properties` (not recommended), using your own config file that you pass to the JVM using the `java.util.logging.config.file` system property, or programmatically.

Depending on your servlet container, it can be configured by different means. For instance, Tomcat will read a `logging.properties` file in your `WEB-INF/classes`: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default)