# Not logging in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, logging

I am working on a GWT project that I have deployed to App Engine. Couple of functionalities are not working as expected, so I am trying to log them to see what the result is. But none of them are getting logged on GAE. Logs are all Info level.

I followed [these](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_Logging) instructions. I have the 'logging.properties' under war/WEB-INF (I even changed the level to Info in logging.ptoperties with no luck), I have made the necessary changes to include the system-properties in the 'appengine-web.xml' file and it is also under war/WEB-INF. I am logging them in the 'EntryPoint' (main) class.

Are there any other changes I need to do?

I really appreciate your input.

Thank you.

> UPDATED :

I updated my program to use the GWT logging now I am getting the following Error:

```
    2014-03-31 13:16:04.768
com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceUtil logOnServer: (TypeError) 

 __gwt$exception: <skipped>: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'null.od')
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) 

 __gwt$exception: <skipped>: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'null.od')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read about [GWT remote logging going to System.out instead of log file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669956/gwt-remote-logging-going-to-system-out-instead-of-log-file?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Braj I updated it to use GWT logging and now I am getting error on logging. I am not sure what exactly it means. I have updated the post with the error. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, GWT logging happens only on the client-side (the browser). If your class (like EntryPoint) is not shared code, then you will not see logs on the server. You must inherit the required GWT module in order to activate GWT (client-side) logging:

```
# In your .gwt.xml file
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
```

Also, if you want to do server-side logging using GWT (i.e. sending logs from the browser to your GAE server), you must use GWT's remote logging facilites. For more info, look here http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Remote_Logging

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. I updated it to use GWT logging and now I am getting error on logging. I am not sure what exactly it means. I have updated the post with the error. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have some sort of `NullPointerException`. It's very hard to debud without seeing the actual GWT code. Maybe you can use GWT's DevMode from within your IDE, and step through the code to discover where that NPE originates from?